# Stumping from fast bowling?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating, wicket

Is it possible to dismiss a batsman by stumping off a fast bowler with the wicket keeper not standing up to the stumps?

To be more specific, for stumping a batsman, is it mandatory to keep the ball within the hands?(since the keeper has to throw the ball to stump the batsman when standing in the normal position for a fast bowler)

If the WK throws the ball to the stumps before the batsman returns to the crease, is this a runout or stumping? (the batsman is not intending to take a run)

Most of the WK are trying to throw the ball with under-arm in this scenario. Are there any rules regarding that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- It is not mandatory to keep the ball within the wicket keeper's hand
  to stump the batsman. He can put the wicket down with ball in his
  hand or thrown on to the stumps.
- It will be given stumped out even if the keeper throws the ball to
  the stumps keeping that there is  no subsequent contact between the
  ball and any other member of the fielding side

[Source - Rules of Cricket - Law 39.](http://www.rulesofcricket.co.uk/the_rules_of_cricket/the_rules_of_cricket_law_39.htm)

- Regarding your final question, there is no rule as how to throw the ball to the stumps. Wicketkeepers often do that because it's quite difficult to throw the ball overarm wearing the keeper's gloves (WK gloves cannot be folded). So it is better to throw underarm to get more control over the throw.